# In Python String are immutable then why the overwrite operation allowed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python String are immutable then why the following operation allowed in Python?

```
a = 'Hello'
a = 'Hi'
```

Comment: Because `a` is not the string. It's a name referencing the string. It can be [re]/[un]bound.

Comment: `a` sees its reference changed in the process.

Comment: The string is immutable. The bound name `a` is not.

Comment: You're not altering the string. You're setting `a` to a _different_ string.

Comment: try `a[0] = 'Z'`

Answer (score 3):

Because `a` is a reference/handle (similar to a pointer if you prefer) to the string, not exactly a string. You can even check the memory address to make sure.

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> id(a)
140102378280544 # memory address (not exactly but that's irrelevant to the topic)
>>> a = 'hii'
140102388086864 # different memory address than before
```

Strings in Python are immutable because there are only stored at one place (mostly), hence cannot be mutated.

```
 >>> a = 'country'
 >>> b = 'country'
 >>> id(a) == id(b)
 True
 >>> a is b
 True
```

Comment: I also know this. My doubt is If string in python is immutable means then why overwritten operation is allowed? What happen in the memory level?Which memory is responsible for this operation?

Comment: @veneth Firstly check my updated answer. Now when you assign new value to `a`, the new value `hii` is not stored in the same memory address as 'hello'. Variables in python are just like pointers that are already dereferences. So, in layman terms, when you are assigning value `hii` to `a`, you are storing `hii` at some memory address and assigning the value of that memory address to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = 'Hello'
>>> id(a)
4519028800
>>> a = 'Hi'
>>> id(a)
4519896088
```

Not the same variable... though I must say the values of `id` are only indicative at best.

When you try to reassign a literal to `a`, you are not changing the string. The string remains the same. What changes is the *reference* that `a` points to.

Comment: Why do you say the `id` values are only indicative?

Comment: Because, in an interpreter session, it is possible for the same values to be reused across variables.